# Measurement for cluster internal quality

Tags: clustering, microarray

I am evaluating a few non-supervised clustering algorithms. One of the questions that I was asked was the internal quality for each algorithms. Any suggestions?

Secondly, what would be an appropriate metric for calculating similarity across the multiple clusters? Most common metrics such as Rand Index only compares between two clusters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably around 30-40 such consistency measures.

The same holds for comparing clusters. ARI is one of the most popular.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Anony-Mousse. I've tried avg silhouette but it wasn't 'sensitive' (for a lack of a better word) enough to pick out the outliers. Perhaps I just have to keep trying different measures... ARI is great for pair-wise comparison, but I was wondering is there are ways to compare multiple groups?

Comment: I don't see how you would use silhouette? And from a pairwise comparison you can trivially go to an n-way distance matrix?